# Ruby on Rails 3: administration interface generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, code-generation, rubygems, administration

I'm looking for some gem/library able to generate administration interface for my RoR3 project.
I don't want to have some library/gem with its own logic and data in some gem repo, I want it to be not just integrated with my app, but be actual part of it, have ability to tweak and modify logic, views, etc...

ATM I've tried [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) and it seems to be the best imho, but during development lots of issues came out: i18n issues, additional pages, custom controls, lack of documentation on extending it, ... There's a lot actually. Maybe for something simple its a perfect match, but not for projects requiring complex administration interface.

So any ideas on gem/library I can use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Active Admin](http://activeadmin.info/):

> Active Admin is a Ruby on Rails plugin for generating administration
>   style interfaces. It abstracts common business application patterns to
>   make it simple for developers to implement beautiful and elegant
>   interfaces with very little effort.